# Error while connecting MYSQL with logstash

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am facing this error while starting logstash.
I have configured MYSQL db as input in logstash.

```
 Pipeline_id:main
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_user=>"admin", jdbc_password=><password>, statement=>"SELECT * from table", jdbc_driver_library=>"/usr/s$
  Error: Permission denied - /.logstash_jdbc_last_run
  Exception: Errno::EACCES
  Stack: org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1237:in `sysopen'
org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3800:in `write'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last_run_metadata_path option [defaults](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/blob/0cee881dcdae5ba75716dacab54aba8da13086b6/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb#L163) to "#{ENV['HOME']}/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", and it looks like that evaluates to /.logstash_jdbc_last_run. You are getting EACCES because you do not have write access to the root directory.

To fix it, set the last_run_metadata_path option to a file in a directory that you have write access to. If you have an input configuration that starts with

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

you can just add an additional line there

```
    last_run_metadata_path => "/tmp/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
```

using some path that you know you can write to and that nobody else will be using.

Comment: I have set it, but hten getting this error :  
 
[2020-11-11T21:46:48,762][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory - /home/$/home/jdbcpath>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3774:in `read'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-integration-jdbc-5.0.6/l$

Comment: Set it to a file, not a directory.

Comment: Yeah that is solved,  now I am able to see the index, but I am facing restarting of the logstash every now and then.
[2020-11-11T22:05:18,604][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2020-11-11T22:05:38,073][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash 

Can u tell me the reason for it?

Comment: Are you using a schedule on the jdbc input? Trying increasing log.level to DEBUG to see if additional messages are logged.